# Prevent last word on a line from being split across lines on R Markdown report

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to use R Markdown to print open ended responses (character strings of any length) to a survey question and I want all of the responses under the same header.  For example, the question "How can this teacher improve?" is stored in a data frame called `d` in a variable called `x`.

Here is an example:

````
---
title: "Teacher Survey"

output:
  html_document 
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)
```
```{r}
d <- data.frame(id = (1:2), x =c("Test to see if word gets split: I kind 
of think that for this teacher to improve they will have make a better 
attempt to attend to the needs of all the students in the classroom", 
"For this teacher to improve they will have make a better attempt to 
attend to the needs of all the students in the classroom"), 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```
###How can this teacher improve
```{r comment=NA}
print(d$x)
```
````

The first response prints "bette" on the first line and "r" on the second line instead of printing "better" all on one line.  How can I make it so "better" prints all on one line?

Comment: Where is your output going? (pdf, notebook, html, word etc).

Comment: The output is html.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

I like using `cat()` instead of `print()`, and specifying `results='asis'` for the chunk.

This way, the text is rendered through the html directly.

````
###How can this teacher improve
```{r comment=NA, results='asis'}
cat(d$x)
```
````

[image: html-preview-1]

Instead of as a `<code/>` block through html.

[image]

Here's a comparison of the html between the first and second images.  Notice the first way starts simply as `<p>Test`, while the second is `<pre><code>[1] &quot;`.

```
<div id="how-can-this-teacher-improve" class="section level3">
<h3>How can this teacher improve</h3>
<p>Test to see if word gets split: I kind of think that for this teacher to improve they will have make a better attempt to attend to the needs of all the students in the classroom For this teacher to improve they will have make a better attempt to attend to the needs of all the students in the classroom</p>
</div>

<div id="how-can-this-teacher-improve" class="section level3">
<h3>How can this teacher improve</h3>
<pre><code>[1] &quot;Test to see if word gets split: I kind \nof think that for this teacher to improve they will have make a better \nattempt to attend to the needs of all the students in the classroom&quot;
[2] &quot;For this teacher to improve they will have make a better attempt to \nattend to the needs of all the students in the classroom&quot;                                                       </code></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: results = 'asis' was very helpful.  I can't use cat because it combines answers from multiple respondents.  I was able to get a format that I like by using                         
    ```{r comment=NA, results='asis'}
    for (i in 1:nrow(d)){
      writeLines(d[i, 2])
      cat("\n")
    }
    ```

Comment: Cool.  Another option is something like `cat(" ", d$x, sep="\n1. ")`.  In this case, it will be in a numbered list, but you can tap into any markdown or html styling/decoration.